# How can I combine masks on a masked array in Numpy?

Tags: python

I want to create a mask for a numpy array by combining two masks using the `masked_where` methods.

```
import numpy as np
a = np.arange(10)
#=> array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9])
a = (ma.masked_less(a,3)) && (ma.masked_greater_equal(a,8))
```

This results in an “invalid syntax” error. Instead, I was expecting an array like:

```
array([-- -- -- 3 4 5 6 7 -- --])
```

How can this be done?

Comment: @Mat with my edit, this question should be OK on Stack Overflow, so let's migrate it there. And “invalid syntax” is literally the whole error message (well, technically the error also points out the location of the error).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Python bitwise and operator is `&`, not `&&`.

```
import numpy as np
a = np.arange(10)
a = np.ma.masked_less(a, 3) & np.ma.masked_greater_equal(a, 8)
```

will work.

Answer (score 0):

This I'd find more elegant than your `ma.masked...`:

```
a = np.arange(10)
#=> array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9])
print a[(a<8)*(a>=3)]
#=> array([3 4 5 6 7])
```

In any case, in your version you need a `np.ma` instead of pure `ma`

...Or do you really want the gaps in `array([-- -- -- 3 4 5 6 7 -- --])` to be filled with something, as `None` for example?

Comment: IPython pylab will automatically import stuff like `ma` from numpy.

Comment: No, he wrote `import numpy as np` in a line above and used `np.arange()`. So no, you are wrong.
Hello, Ilja^^

Comment: Missed the import, so yeah. And hello!

Comment: I agree with Ilja